# Enabling form fields in case of minor

Tags: javascript, forms, datepicker

[form field screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT4p5.png)

I am collecting nominees data from users for nomination in my organization. The form fields have been attached as image for your reference.

I use iondatepicker for the date field. In case the date of birth chosen by the users for the nominee works out to be the age of a minor i want the fields of the minors' guardian data to be enabled. else they should remain as disabled or with the value 'NA'. Please find below the codes for the form fields.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="result-1">
                <input style="width: 600px;" type="text" value="" name="dob" id="mydate" 
                    data-lang="en" data-years="1925-2018" size="10" maxlength="10" 
                    placeholder='date of birth of nominee (dd/mm/yyyy)' data-format="DD/MM/YYYY" 
                    class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <b>If Nominee is a Minor, give 
            GUARDIAN's Particulars</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="width: 600px;" 
                type="text" name="g_name" id="g_name"  size="30" maxlength="200" 
                placeholder='Guardian Name' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="width: 600px;" 
                type="text" name="g_relation" id="g_relation"  size="30" maxlength="200" 
                placeholder='Guardian Relationship with you' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="width: 600px;" 
                type="text" name="g_address" id="g_address"  size="30" maxlength="200" 
                placeholder='Guardian Address' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solution (assuming you are not using any libraries like jQuery or moment.js, it's in plain javascript):

```js
var myDate = document.getElementById('mydate')

myDate.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  var val = e.target.value
  var date = new Date(val)
   
  if ( isNaN( date.getDate())  ){
    alert('Wrong date format!')
    return;
  }
  
  var compareDate = new Date()
  compareDate.setFullYear(compareDate.getFullYear()-18)
  
  
  if(compareDate < date){
     document.getElementById('g_name').value=""
     document.getElementById('g_relation').value=""
     document.getElementById('g_address').value=""
     document.getElementById('g_name').disabled=false
     document.getElementById('g_relation').disabled=false
     document.getElementById('g_address').disabled=false
  }else{
     document.getElementById('g_name').value="NA"
     document.getElementById('g_relation').value="NA"
     document.getElementById('g_address').value="NA"
     document.getElementById('g_name').disabled=true
     document.getElementById('g_relation').disabled=true
     document.getElementById('g_address').disabled=true
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="result-1">
                <input style="width: 600px;" type="text" value="" name="dob" id="mydate" 
                    data-lang="en" data-years="1925-2018" size="10" maxlength="10" 
                    placeholder='date of birth of nominee (dd/mm/yyyy)' data-format="DD/MM/YYYY" 
                    class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            <b>If Nominee is a Minor, give 
            GUARDIAN's Particulars</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="width: 600px;" 
                type="text" name="g_name" id="g_name"  size="30" maxlength="200" disabled
                placeholder='Guardian Name' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="width: 600px;" 
                type="text" name="g_relation" id="g_relation"  size="30" maxlength="200" disabled  
                placeholder='Guardian Relationship with you' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="width: 600px;" 
                type="text" name="g_address" id="g_address"  size="30" maxlength="200" disabled 
                placeholder='Guardian Address' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable code. your code works like a charm without the datepicker. When i select the date via the datepicker the change even in the script is not called. hence the form fields remain disabled irrespective of the date selected. since all websites today use datepicker rather than manual entry of dates, it would be hihgly helpful if the datepicker could trigger the change event and disables/Enables the form field

Comment: It all depends what kind of datepicket are you using. Sometimes the datepickers create another hidden element where they store the value, so you need to bind the change event on that element. Please update your question with the code that enables the datepicker and i will update my answer to accomodate the solution